# What is the maven dependency with artifactId "oracle"?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I joined a project that has been stable for years and has seen no (or almost none) additional development in the last 4 or 5 years or so.
I'm having build problems with the dependencies.
I can't figure out what the following dependency is for.
This is written in multiple pom.xml's.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

There is also a parent pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**What does this dependency refer to and what does it do?**

I tried to look up this dependency but practically all results refer to jdbc.
Is this the same as JDBC?
Is this an old name for something that is currently not used anymore?

Is it the same as this ojdbc14 dependency?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Here is the [dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) documentation which explains pretty much everything you are asking about dependency management. ojdbc14 is the driver for connecting Oracle's PostgreSQL database. JDBC is an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to connect to Databases, which is implemented in one of those drivers you use.

Comment: Thank you @techtabu, that's a very useful comment! If you could elaborate a bit on the first dependency code block I'm sure you could turn it into a great answer! Reading the dependency management now.

Comment: Hey, I am running into same questions. I don't have any problems with dependenciyMangement, but here is the real question underlying this topic : What's the difference between <com.oracle.oracle> and <com.oracle.ojdbc14> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, your old coders follow the proper standards, the first one is defined under `dependencyManagement`. Let's say you have a parent and some sub modules and these sub modules share some dependencies. So, you define these common dependencies in the parent pom, so that you can make sure you maintain consistency in your project. Things like version, java version, and other configurations can be defined in parent pom.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

Now that you have defined the configuration in the parent pom, whenever you want to use it in the sub modules, you just specify `groupId` and `artifactId`. The point is, just because you define in the parent pom under `dependencyManagement`, it does not mean it will be available in the sub modules unless you manually specify you want to use that dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here, you omit the version information. The sub module will look parent for that information and use it. The wording itself suggest, in parent you use `dependencyManagement`. i.e. It's just managing the dependencies. In the sub modules, you use them under `dependencies`.

Comment: Spot on! Thank a lot :) Do you also happen to know what this dependency specifically does? I assume it has something to do with the database but the jdbc dependency is a different one. Searching for com.oracle oracle [here](https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.oracle%22%20AND%20a%3A%22oracle%22) also returns no results.

Comment: No, I don't know. May be a proprietary one from Oracle. Try to find it in the code, where it is used.